# Setting VSCode build setting to a Eclipse's java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have a project that I'm working in using Eclipse as the IDE. I hate eclipse and prefer to use VSCode/VS. I was wondering is there a setting/plugin that I can set up so that my VSCode can build the project and able to debug from VSCode?

I have the Java extensions installed, but I'm not sure how to copy the build setting of Eclipse to it.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code allows you to debug Java applications through the [Debugger for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug) extension. It's a lightweight Java debugger based on Java Debug Server, which extends the [Language Support for Java by Red Hat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java), and **Language Support for Java by Red Hat** provides Java ™ language support via `Eclipse ™ JDT Language Server`, which utilizes `Eclipse ™ JDT`, `M2Eclipse` and `Buildship`. So you don't have to copy the build setting of Eclipse to VS Code.

Detailed steps about Debugging please refer to [Run and Debug Java in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging).

Comment: @user10416282. Does this answer help solve your question? If it does, it's appreciated that you accept it as the answer. Don't hesitate to let me know if you have any other questions.